# Filtering with Filebeat and regex

Tags: regex, filter, filebeat

Saw a similar post regarding filtering Filebeat output, but my case is complicated by the existence of a double quote and slashes and backslashes within the message string.

Here is the message field in Filebeat:

"message":"162.246.216.28 - msca.operations [03/May/2017:17:21:21 +0000] \"GET /api/console/proxy?uri=*aliases\u0026*=1493758138223 **HTTP/1.1\" 200** 60 \"http

As seen above, to remove all successful HTTP requests, I need to capture both the "HTTP" and the returned status "200" and dump them.

I tried this line, and a few variations without success:

```
- drop_event:
when:
    regexp:
       message: "*HTTP?1.1?? 200*"
```

Comment: What did you get? and what is the exact output you are expecting?

Comment: Find `HTTP[^"]*\"\s*\d+\s*` replace with nothing. Stringed regex = `"HTTP[^\"]*\\\"\\s*\\d+\\s*"` But remember, this removes the `\"` which might unbalance it somewhere down the line.

Comment: Try: `*HTTP.1\.1"\s*200*`

Comment: Filebeat uses regex in this instance to determine which lines to include/exclude.  Using TheChetan's  example (which seemed the simplest) caused an error with unknown escape sequence.   sln's solution seems to have worked, but not sure what might be unbalanced... :)

Comment: Hmm.   sln seems to remove all http, not just the 200's.   Sigh.